# Is it possible to maintain the original function header after typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript

Normally one can view the function information by doing:

```
function somefunction(arg1, { a, b, c}){}

someFunction.toString()
```

... compile and run

```
//function somefunction(arg1, { a, b, c}){}
```

but when typescript compiles the code, any function that may have deconstructed arguments, gets replaced with _a:

```
function someOtherFunction(arg1, { a, b, c}){}

console.log(someOtherFunction.toString())
```

... compile and run

```
//function someOtherFunction(arg1, _a){}
```

Is there anyway to retrieve the original deconstructed argument information while still using typescript?

I've dug around in the TS issue tracker, but got lost in the many issues. Nothing seems to stick out with an initial search however.

**EDIT**
Since I was trying to do this with ts-node, the solution was changing both the target and the module as outlined here: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/678. This effectively ensures the compiled code is es6 code which doesnt strip the deconstruction!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: don't destructure arguments that way. its not compatible with most browsers. typescript is trying to get to max compatability.

Comment: When it runs in the browser, it will run the transpiled js code. Currently, you have set the target to ES5. If you change target to ES2015+, it will keep the destructuring in the transpiled .js file

Comment: This is specifically node code, so the compatibility with browsers is a lesser concern for me atm :). As for the transpilation target, that makes complete sense. I had to change it to es5 for ts-node to work. Ill see if i can find a way around it then! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `Function.prototype.toString()` will *always* print out the compiled javascript, so it depends on your target because that changes how it's compiled. There is no setting to change that because this is a feature runtime javascript, which isn't something that Typescript could have any influence over at compile time.

Take this simple example:

```
function someFunction(
    arg1: string,
    { a, b, c }: {a: string, b: string, c: string}
){}
alert(someFunction.toString())
```

If the target is ES5 or lower, deconstructing assignment is not available. So the compiler makes restructuring assignment work without assuming the environment supports it. It does that by changes your arguments to accomplish the same thing.

[Example with ES3 target (click Run)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgChFTEBDAJwHMBGALhSkpjGoBoSyBvC9xAEb8IiAL6Nu5RsmasOg6bLbDFLNqKIBKbhqLkANhkpQCqTDkiwEAOihwAykuoFNmoA)

[Example with ES2015 target (click Run)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgChFTEBDAJwHMBGALhSkpjGoBoSyBvC9xAEb8IiAL6Nu5RsmasOg6bLbDFLNqKIBKbhqLkANhkpQCqTDkiwEAOihwAykuoFNmoA)

---

So you can "fix" this by changing your target, but then your target environment better have support for destructuring. But if your compiling to support older environments, then calling `toString()` will always return the body of the function compiled to work in your target environment.

Comment: Yea that seems to be my problem. Im trying to use ts-node to run a ts script but it requires a compilation down to commonjs to work. Ill try another way around this! Thank you!